# Abelian Sandpile Model in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, logic

I am attempting to make an Abelian Sandpile Model in PHP. I am getting started with a possible solution, and it is working for three dimensional array but not working for 5 dimensional array. I am not sure why the following issue is occurring.

```
$pile = array(array(0,1,0),array(0,2,3),array(1,0,1));
```

**Expected  : 021, 110, 112**

Actual result : 021, 110, 112

```
$pile = array(array(0,0,3,0,0),array(0,0,3,0,0),array(3,3,3,3,3),array(0,0,3,0,0),array(0,0,3,0,0));
```

**Expected : 01010, 12321, 03030, 12321, 01010**

Actual result : 01010, 12221, 02020, 12221, 01010

**PHP Script:**

```
<?php
//$pile = array(array(0,1,0),array(0,2,3),array(1,0,1));
//expected     : 021, 110, 112
//$result = sandpile($pile, 2);

$pile = array(array(0,0,3,0,0),array(0,0,3,0,0),array(3,3,3,3,3),array(0,0,3,0,0),array(0,0,3,0,0));
//expected     : 01010, 12321, 03030, 12321, 01010

$result = sandpile($pile, 5);

function sandpile($pile, $n)
  {
    $total_rows = count($pile);
    $mid_x      = (int) ($total_rows / 2);
    $mid_y      = (int) (count($pile[$mid_x]) / 2);

    $arr_result = array_redistribute($pile, $mid_x, $mid_y, $n);

    return $arr_result;
  }

function array_redistribute($arr_input = array(), $x, $y, $n = 1)
  {
    $arr_input[$x][$y] = $arr_input[$x][$y] + $n;

    // if grains in a cell reaches 4
    if ($arr_input[$x][$y] > 3)
      {
        $arr_input[$x][$y] = 0;

        // increment closest cell
        if(isset($arr_input[$x-1][$y]))
    $arr_input[$x-1][$y] = $arr_input[$x-1][$y] + 1;

    if(isset($arr_input[$x+1][$y]))
    $arr_input[$x+1][$y] = $arr_input[$x+1][$y] + 1;

    if(isset($arr_input[$x ][$y-1]))
    $arr_input[$x ][$y-1] = $arr_input[$x][$y-1] +1;

    if(isset($arr_input[$x][$y+1]))
    $arr_input[$x][$y+1] = $arr_input[$x][$y+1] + 1;

    // if closest cell value > 3
    if(isset($arr_input[$x-1][$y]) && $arr_input[$x-1][$y]>3)
    {
      $arr_input = array_redistribute($arr_input, $x-1, $y, 1);
    }

    if(isset($arr_input[$x+1][$y]) && $arr_input[$x+1][$y]>3)
    {
      $arr_input = array_redistribute($arr_input, $x+1, $y, 1);
    }

    if(isset($arr_input[$x][$y-1]) && $arr_input[$x][$y-1]>3)
    {
      $arr_input = array_redistribute($arr_input, $x, $y-1, 1);
    }

    if(isset($arr_input[$x ][$y+1]) && $arr_input[$x][$y+1]>3)
    {
      $arr_input = array_redistribute($arr_input, $x, $y+1, 1);
    }

    return $arr_input;
  }
?>
```

Comment: `$arr_input[$x][$y] = 0;` really?

Comment: @user58697, yes in this case if grains in a cell reaches 4 then grains goes down to zero in the center cell and each neighbor receives 1 grain.

Comment: What if it reached 5?

Comment: @user58697, no it will not  reach 5. Each cell value should be less than 4 and if reaches 4 then that cell goes down to zero and each neighbor cell will increase its value by 1. I hope this is clear.

Comment: Please doublecheck. There are avalanches. Consider the cell with the count of 3, having two neighbors also with the count of 3. Both neighbors reach 4, and each spills 1 to the cell in question. Just for the peace of mind, try `$arr_input[$x][$y] -= 4;` and see for yourself.

Comment: @user58697, I tried and getting different output but not expected :(